# Grunt - create empty file

Tags: file, gruntjs

How to create a new empty file in a Grunt task?

I want to set up a project and create a new file in the process. The file will be empty. I don't want to use unnecessary plugins that are not intended for this purpose.

Is there a simple way to do such thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [grunt.file.write](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.write):

```
grunt.registerTask('emptyFile', 'Creates an empty file', function() {
   grunt.file.write('path/to/file', '');
});
```

Comment: How can I resolve a variable? E.g.: `grunt.file.write('<%= config.dist %>/some_file', '')` creates a folder named `<%= config.dist %>`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Nevermind, it should be `grunt.file.write(config.dist + '/some_file', '')`, good ole js concatenation.